# Insert records into embedded field of OrientDB class from select

Tags: sql, orientdb

I am evaluating OrientDB database.

I have two document classes imported from a relational database.

```
class Order with properties (ID: integer, OrderItems: EmbeddedList of OrderItem)
```

and

```
class OrderItem with properties (ID: integer, OrderID: integer, PropA: string)
```

Both classes are filled with data from the database (except field Order.OrderItems).

Now I would like to insert data from class OrderItem into class Order based on OrderID.

I have tried SQL like

```
update Order set OrderItems = (select from OrderItem where OrderID = Order.ID)
```

without success, with error like

The field 'Order.OrderItems' has been declared as EMBEDDEDLIST but the value is document with the valid RecordId ...

I do understand that embedded record should not have RecordId so I have tried

```
update Order set OrderItems = (select PropA from OrderItem where OrderID = Order.ID)
```

without success, with error like

The field 'Order.OrderItems' has been declared as EMBEDDEDLIST with linked class 'OrderItem' but the record has no class ...

I have also tried

```
update Order
set OrderItems = (select @class, PropA from OrderItem where OrderID = Order.ID)
```

without success.

Is there any other way (OrientDB 2.1.4) ...

Ales

Answer (score 2):

I have found the solution

```
update Order
set OrderItems = (select $current.exclude('@rid') from OrderItem where $parent.$current.ID = OrderID)
```