# Set embedded field using Document API

Tags: orientdb

Related to https://github.com/orientechnologies/orientdb/issues/3612 and [Insert records into embedded field of OrientDB class from select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33186867/insert-records-into-embedded-field-of-orientdb-class-from-select)

With the develop branch (2.2),

```
ODocument product = new ODocument("Product");
ODocument data = new ODocument("Price");
data.field("currency", "EUR");
product.field("data", data);
product.save();
```

raises this kind of error with a transactional database (whereas it works with a non tx) :

```
The field 'Product.price' has been declared as EMBEDDED but the value is a document with the valid RecordID Price#220:-3
```

Is it a bug ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have tried with 2.2 snapshot and it works

```
ODatabaseDocumentTx db = new ODatabaseDocumentTx(path);
db.open("root","root");
db.command(new OCommandSQL("create class Product")).execute();
db.command(new OCommandSQL("create property Product.data EMBEDDED")).execute();
db.getMetadata().getSchema().reload();

ODocument product = new ODocument("Product");
ODocument data = new ODocument("Price");
data.field("currency", "EUR");
product.field("data", data);
product.save();
```